# how to check whether a data/payload can be decoded by protobuf or not

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, protobufjs

I have files with data (payload) in different formats (plain text, json, xlm, binary (can be decoded by protobuf)). To know how to process particular file I need to know what is the format of data in the file.

The question is whether it is possible to recognize without having .proto (message) file that the payload in a file can be decoded by protobuf. So, if I know that it is protobuf encoded data, I will apply one logic where .proto file is required, otherwise, another logic without .proto file.

All what I've found requires to have protobuf message to validate/decode.

Comment: Don't quite follow - can't you just check the file extension?

Comment: I corrected title and question. Obviously I was not fully correct and mixed "protobuf format" with "binary" which can be decoded using protobuf

Answer (score 0):

Usually `.proto` files have something like `syntax = "proto3";` as one of the first lines of the file. This does not apply to `proto2` syntax though.

Maybe you can make use of that?

Comment: no, I don't want to use .proto before I'm sure that file data (payload) is of protobuf format